# Align contents of two table columns together

Tags: html, html-email

Working on an email template trying to make it a 2 column email with a Date and Message column. I was able to get the columns working using a table but now it doesnt quite line up correctly.

[image]

This is the code that builds the html

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateColumns">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="50%" class="templateColumnContainer">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <div class='label'>Date</div>
                                <td valign="top" class="leftColumnContent">
                                    <div class='value'><?= $title; ?> </div><br>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="50%" class="templateColumnContainer">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <div class='label'>Message</div>
                                <td valign="top" class="rightColumnContent">
                                    <div class='value'><?= $title1; ?> </div><br>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Is there a way to change the HTML so that each entry lines up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to doing with tables within tables.  Tables by default will line up rows, that's what it does. Looks like you have 1 row and put all your data for each column into a single cell.

One row to define your table headers; Date and Message

The a new row for each line of data.

```
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateColumns">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?= $title; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $title1; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Do your two variables contain all that column data in each one? Like, does $title contain that entire list of dates? If so, we'll need to parse that data out using some javascript